# How to upgrade Mysql Client Version?

Tags: mysql

Hello guys can you help me with my problem? I am having an issue about using mysqldump. After proccessing this line of code

```
mysqldump -h192.xxx.xxx.xx -uxxx -pxxx xxx > C:\databases\xxx.sql
```

I got an error

```
mysqldump: Couldn't execute 'SET OPTION SQL_QUOTE_SHOW_CREATE=1': You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'OPTION SQL_QUOTE_SHOW_CREATE=1' at line 1 (1064)
```

And I searched in the Internet how to solve this issue. And I found a solution that I need to upgrade my mysql client version. By the way I am using MySql 5.5.20.

How can I upgrade the client version? I am using WAMP server. Or is there any other way to solve my problem in using mysqldump?

That's all guys. Thanks.

Comment: One more situation where a software management system is such a practical thing to have. Two clicks and all available version just one more click away...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Client tools come with the WAMP / LAMP install if you're running mysqldump on the WAMP  Server. You will have to upgrade to 5.6.5. That should fix SET OPTION.

See here [MySQL Bugs](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=66765)